# IBM Db2 Visual Studio 2010 Table Adapter Problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, db2, datatableadapters

I am using db2 database on my localhost and I want to use TableAdapter in my web project. When I connect the database with server explorer the table names doesn't shown. I checked the privileges of the user and give them full access. The db2admin user has full control on the database, the connection is succeed but the table names is not showing in the server explorer. I can see database procedures only. I can connect a remote database server and there is no problem. I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7. I have installed sp1 for visual Studio. Can someone help me?..Sorry for my english by the way.

Answer (score 1):

What version of DB2 Data Driver are you using? if you are using the 9.7fp3 beta try upgrading to 9.7 FP4 which was just released in April (no longer beta). 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=368836&tstart=0

Be sure you install the Add-Ins for Visual Studio as well which is required for it to work. That also means it won't work with VS2010 Express since Express does not support add-ins.